# regex 'dark' or 'light' in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How would one write regex for matching 'dark' OR 'light' in javascript. It would be the complete words that would be replaced.

Comment: Where's your problem? What have you tried? Don't you know [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), or don't you know [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
str.match(/\b(dark|light)\b/g)
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/zhggQ/

Comment: The groups are unnecessary, but this is the answer.

Comment: Not really. This also matches `lighthouse` or `darken`, and @re1man said that he needs to match whole words.

Comment: Actually, better yet, use word boundaries for better reading: `/\b(dark|light)\b/` http://jsfiddle.net/uRUM2/1/

Comment: Agreed. Man I need to re-read my Mastering Regular Expressions O'Reilly book. Been at least 5 years hah.

Answer (score 2):

```
/\b(?:dark|light)\b/g
```

to match only whole words. Have a look at

- the [`replace` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) of strings
- what the [global flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global) means
- [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- and [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

"dark or light".replace(/(dark|light)/g,"other")

Answer (score 0):

/(\sdark\s|\slight\s)/
You need to cater optional leading or trailing space around the words

Comment: Why?  It sounds like he wants to match the whole word.